# Fetch data from Other Websites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-3.5

Even before telling my question, will tell you that this is a very vague question. But please let me know if you have any similar ideas.

I am actually trying to write a website of my own locally using ASP.Net. I actually wanted to try and simulate a website with trading and stock details. I wanted to actually fetch the details from some were. Please let me know if it is possible to fetch data from another website or is there any site where i can fetch such details. Also please let me know of what all parameters i need to keep in mind before and while designing a website. Please let me know any such ideas which i can make use of. Thank you one and all very very much. Any comment from you is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use ASP.Net to fetch data from other websites, though generally speaking if you're planning on making a large site the scraping off other sites is done "offline", and the ASP.Net application serves off this cache of crawled pages.  Keep in mind that heavy traffic coming from a single IP (ie, your server) is likely to raise flags with a sysadmin unless you have a prior agreement with the site, and you might just get your IP banned to cool it down.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can fetch data using **System.Net** classes such as **System.Net.WebClient**.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the basics you can begin looking into is the **HttpWebRequest** & **HttpWebResponse** classes, below is a simple example grabbed from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)

```
    // Create an HttpWebRequest using WebRequest.Create (see .NET docs)!
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);


    // Execute the request and obtain the response
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally I'd grab data like that from a webservice provided by the data source. Although I doubt you could find such a service for free.